# How to clear CPU cached owned by a process in Linux x86

Tags: linux

I want to get the kernel APIs which can be used to flush/clear the CPU cache owned by a specific process.

Comment: This maybe? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system

Comment: @LuS. no. These are not the caches OP referred to.

Comment: The cache is a shared resource, so you probably cannot do it for one process. You will probably evict code/data for all processes. Also see the `cflush` instruction for x86.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, you are right, I am looking for the way to clear/flush the CPU cache (L1/L2/L3), not the page cache/buffer cache for IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "CPU cache owned by a process".

The CPU / memory controller manages the cache, not the OS.

On some CPU architectures (I don't know!) it might be possible to explicitly instruct the caches to evoke ("invalidate") certain cache lines, but that's probably more along the lines of pretty specific DMA controller commands than a Linux API thing.

I think your question might be born from a superficial understanding of Meltdown/Spectre. If that's the case: re-read the original papers and read up on x86 CPU cache implementations.

Comment: You are right again! ;-).
I am looking for the way to work with X86 CPU cache.
And it stems from the checking on Meltdown/Spectre.
I really worked out a POC of fix to Meltdown (except TSX) in Linux X868_64.

It is here, https://github.com/wangtao13/poc_fix_meltdown.

I really appreciate your comments to the POC.

Thanks,
Tao